# how i post my apps activity on facebook activity section

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I am working on a facebook apps,i want to post may apps activity on facebook activity section.

I am using this code

```
    try {
        $params = array(
            'message'       =>  "Hurray! This works :)",
            'name'          =>  "This is my title",
            'caption'       =>  "My Caption",
            'description'   =>  "Some Description...",
            'link'          =>  "http://stackoverflow.com",
            'picture'       =>  "http://i.imgur.com/VUBz8.png",
        );

        $post = $facebook->api("/$user/feed","POST",$params);



    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
       $result = $e->getResult();
    }
```

this is working but the message show on facebook wall.I want the message show on facebook activity section.Anyone know about this please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The [Facebook Developer Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/) describes the process and from there you will find that you need to define actions for the namespace that you are going to be using and use:

```
$facebook->api('/me/{namespace}:{action-type-name}');
```

Where `{namespace}` is your app's namespace and `{action-type-name}` is the action that you define in your [Developer's Admin Panel](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) under the OpenGraph Section of the application.

Comment: Thanks for answering.I have used this code but it give error "Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Unknown path components: /movie:review} thrown in E:\xampp\htdocs\filmclub\facebook\base_facebook.php on line 1238" where movie is my namespace and review is action

Comment: Your namespace is `movie` as in `https://apps.facebook.com/movie/`? I could not find that app on Facebook at all, you need to make it `'/me/myappname:review'`

Comment: i have created namesopace filmclub_ but the problem is same

Comment: You have to _define_ your Open Graph actions and objects as well.